# compare executable or object file

Tags: linux, compare, elf, strip

I have two file that are supposed to be generated from same source version. One of the files is stripped.
Is possible to compare the raw executable portion of the files to establish if they are the same?
Can be done also on object files (and in particular on .ko linux kernel modules)?

Answer (score 11):

I would try using

```
objdump -d file1>a
objdump -d file2>b
diff a b
```

or, as F.Hauri suggested,

```
diff <(objdump -d file1) <(objdump -d file2)
```

-d option disassembles the executable portions of the files.

However, there is always a possibility that different compilers would generate different byte- and hence, assembly, code. 
Also, I am not sure of the order of the object files in the executable, if there are more than one.
for the object file that is compiled with the same compiler that should work.

Comment: Using [tag:bash], you coud write: `diff <(objdump -d file1) <(objdump -d file2)` without having to use temporary files! ;-)

Comment: Try it with `diff -y ... | less -S` in a wide console

Comment: I have to say in some rare case (which I am unfortunately in), if two versions of the source code have only data (those bytes put into .data, .rodata, etc. sections) difference, the disassembled code would be the same, causing the compare result by this method false negative. Anyhow, in normal cases, this method worth trying.

Answer (score 3):

You can run `objdump -x <file>` to list the sections of the program, and then `objcopy -j <section> <file> <out>` to extract those sections and compare them.

You'll want to skip the debugging sections and check the likes of `.text`, `.data`...

Answer (score 2):

You can use diffoscope to compare two .so files, use html option to view the differences in any browser, after installing diffoscope try this:

`diffoscope --html output.html first_file second_file`

An outfile.html file will be created in the current directory you can see the differences in this, section by section.

Answer (score 2):

[elf_diff](https://github.com/CapeLeidokos/elf_diff) compares ELF files (object files, shared libraries, archives, ...) and generates html or pdf reports of the differences. Its focus lies on exploring assembly level changes and resource consumption.
A similarity detection engine performs fuzzy matches between symbol names and also assembly code and presents pairs of symbols from the compared binaries that are likely being related, e.g. due to having been renamed.
elf_diff helps understanding the effects of changes to  high level language code, say C or C++ on program storage and static RAM usage.
Originaly being geared towards embedded development, the tool may be useful in other environments, too.

Haven't tried elf_diff with kernel module files yet but as those are ELF files as well, I would expect it to work.

Answer (score 1):

[elfcmp](https://github.com/dnezamaev/pyelfcmp) compares both ELF file's inner structures like file header, sections, segments, etc. Then you can print it on screen or use in your application. It requires python installed.